# generate a pdf file an asp.net(ajax) c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation

I have a web page in which user has to enter many details.

I want to fetch the records that are being entered by the user and generate a pdf file, and also preview it in a browser.

I also want to save the pdf into the database.

Can anyone help me to understand how this process should start?? I mean how should I proceed?

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and mysql. I have adobe reader installed on my system. What else do I need?

Can I get the tutorials or code samples which will help me.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Reader is just what it says, a Reader application, and will not help with generating a PDF. I recommend you to have a look at [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a third party library for the pdf generation, such as [Report.net](http://report.sourceforge.net/) or [ITextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).

The problem I see with browser preview, is that I don't know of a good way of doing it. If you just want to show them the data that goes in to the PDF, then just displaying that on a web page is easy enough. The problem is previewing the actual PDF. That will require the user to have some sort of PDF reader installed, and it will also require that their browser opens the PDF automatically and doesn't try to save it instead. It also has the problem of how the user will "get back" to your website once they're done with the previewing.

Comment: can you please explain me displaying a pdf on a web page?